# godoc no match found error

Tags: go, godoc

I am new to `Go` and am writing a test application and would like to document it. My application is in `GOHOME\src\myapp`.

I could use the following command to start a server and use a browser to view the documents. This worked:

```
$ godoc -http=":5050"
```

However, I would like to generate HTML files and copy the files to a server so other people could read them. I tried:

```
$ godoc myapp -zip="1.zip"
```

and

```
$ godoc myapp -zip="1.zip" -index=true
```

I always get the following error:

> No match found.

What should I do so that I can generate all document files?

Comment: The zip option specifies the file system to serve, not where to write data. If the zip option is not specified, then godoc serves the directory tree $GOPATH.  If you are publishing your code publicly to bitbucket, github, etc, then use godoc.org to view your doc.

Comment: Thanks for the quick update. So is there any options to generate documents like Javadoc, so we could host on a different server?